# Difference between model.evaluate and metrics.accuracy_score

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, metrics, evaluation

I am trying to evaluate CNN model using two different approaches:

1.

```
model.evaluate(test_data)
```

In this case I get 79% accuracy score: [1.2163524627685547, 0.7924528121948242]

2.

I want to get the actual prediction values and use scikit-learn metrics to get accuracy score:

```
test_prediction=model.predict(test_data)
test_prediction=np.argmax(test_prediction, axis=1)

y_test = np.concatenate([y_batch for X_batch, y_batch in test_data])

metrics.accuracy_score(test_prediction,y_test)
```

The accuracy score is 21% in this case.

Why is there difference and which way is more reliable?

Comment: plot test_prediction againts y_test to verify the metrics

Comment: I plotted prediction vs actuals using seaborn's heatmap. Each cell has accuracy of around 4-5%. I think , for some reason actual y_test values are shuffled and don't correspond to predictions, or vise versa.
There are 5 classes in total and I always get aroundn 19%-20% accuracy using scikit learn metrics approact. (100%/5 is approximately 19-20%)

Comment: @beridzeg45 could you provide your code with the training and how you define your y_test

Comment: @DataSciRookie
Here is the code: https://github.com/beridzeg45/Machine-Learning/blob/main/Computer_Vision/cv_flowers%20recognition(tf%20template).ipynb